# Count and display result based on type in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I have the following table

```
|id|user_type|
|1|Customers|
|2|Suppliers|
|3|Customers|
|4|Suppliers|
|5|Suppliers|
|6|Employees|
```

I want to count total customers, suppliers, employess

Customers (2)

Suppliers (3)

Employees (1)

Here are my html

```
       <a href="#" class="customers list-group-item">
            <span class="badge badge-info">
                 2
            </span>
            Customers
       </a>
        <a href="#" class="employees list-group-item">
            <span class="badge badge-danger">
                3               
           </span>
            Employees           
       </a>
        <a href="#" class="suppliers list-group-item">
            <span class="badge badge-success">
                1               
              </span>
            Suppliers           
       </a>
```

My query code look like this

```
     <?php
                 $this->load->model("User_model");
                 $query = $this->db->query('SELECT user_type, COUNT(Customers) AS total FROM `users` GROUP BY user_type');

       if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        $data['users'] = array(
            'total' => $row->total,
        );

echo $data['users'];
```

This code does not working. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `$data['users']` is overwritten on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$data['users']` variable is overwritten on each iteration of `foreach`.
What ou need to do - is to **add new item** to `$data['users']`. Adding to array is perfomed with `[]`:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $data['users'][] = array(
        'type_name' => $row->user_type,
        'total' => $row->total,
    );
}

// `echo` will no work with `arrays`, use `print_r` instead
print_r($data['users']);
```

Comment: Sir, I am getting an errorA Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Customers' in 'field list'

SELECT user_type, COUNT(Customers) AS jobcount FROM `users` GROUP BY user_type

Comment: Your column name is `user_type` so it is `COUNT(user_type) as total` , please be careful.

Comment: I do not want to count user_type but want to count Customers, Suppliers and Employees column

Comment: Please run your query with `COUNT(user_type) as total` and __see the results__.